# Can we use double quotes for strings inside t()?

Tags: users

Is it correct what said in the comment [#7](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923151#comment-12346760) for [Usernames allow @ symbol](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923151)?

> t() value should write in single quotes not in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is a string... PhP allows strings to be defined [four ways](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), but the two that apply here are 'xxx' and "xxx"... both are valid strings that will be passed to the t() function.  The function cannot determine how the string variable was created, it only gets the content between the delimiters.  So you can use either one.

That said, some people like the convention of using single quotes for straight constant strings since '$foo' = $foo... while "$foo" = value of $foo.  AFAIK, Drupal coding standards do not specify what can be used for a string.

Adendum:  Note that the string being passed to the t() function should be a static string in order to be translatable.  E.g. if you use "$foo", this would be impossible to translate.  That's what the placeholders are for.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `t()` needs to be a literal string. Using single quotes or double quotes as string delimiters doesn't make any difference for PHP, but the [Drupal coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards) says the following, about using [quotes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#quotes). (Emphasis is mine.)

> Drupal does not have a hard standard for the use of single quotes vs. double quotes. Where possible, keep consistency within each module, and respect the personal style of other developers.
>
> With that caveat in mind, **single quote strings should be used by default**. Their use is recommended **except in two cases**:
>
> 1. Deliberate in-line variable interpolation, e.g. `"<h2>$header</h2>"`.
> 2. **Translated strings** where one **can avoid escaping single quotes by enclosing the string in double quotes**. One such string would be "He's a good person." It would be 'He\'s a good person.' with single quotes. Such escaping may not be handled properly by .pot file generators for text translation, and it's also somewhat awkward to read.

Since the literal string is `"Several special characters are allowed, including space, period (.), hyphen (-), apostrophe ('), underscore (_), and the @ sign."` and it contains an apostrophe, by the second point it should be delimited by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects to this question:

1. PHP of course allows allows either quote style, so it doesn't matter to the actual code.
2. The syntax of `t()` calls does matter more than usual in PHP, because they are parsed by static analysers to extract translation strings and generate `.po` files. However, this parser also allows either quote style. (The argument does have to be a single fixed string without variables or concatenation, though.)
3. In this specific case, it's about a core patch, where strict code-style standards come in. Drupal recommends single-quotes wherever possible, with two exceptions, which brings us to:
4. One exception is [quotes containing apostrophes/single-quotes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#quotes), as double quotes let you avoid backslashes. As the particular example *does* contain an apostrophe, the double quotes are justified.